# I'm trying to create a Web App using Django, I've encountered unknown 500 errors I can't debug

Tags: django, django-errors

**This is the error that occurs, it seems to happen when I request a .html file from my templates folder but for some unknown reason to me it fails to show and throws these errors I haven't been able to figure out for a couple days.**

**If additional information is needed I will provide it thank you to anyone who assists**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\pages\views.py", line 5, in index
    return render(request, 'index.html')
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\uknow\Desktop\Coding\GoFishFarms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html
[25/Jul/2020 13:29:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 82139
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GbPw.png)

Comment: Can you share your `views.py` and directory structure for templates?

Comment: There you go I added the views.py and directory screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you correctly set up the directory structure (best practice) and now when Django 'sets up' the main templates folder it will look like this **templates/, templates/pages/index.html, templates/pages/about.html**. `render()` will automatically get the **templates/** part so you have to give it the rest - `render(request, 'pages/index.html')`

**IMPORTANT**
Remember to add pages app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'pages',
...
]
```

otherwise Django will not attach *pages* to your templates folder

Comment: I already had the pages app installed and I fixed the views.py as you said I'm still getting the same error and cannot fix it. I'm going to abandon Django and Python see if another language would better fit me for backend.